# Gitlab merge "merge request" with commit

Tags: merge, gitlab, merge-request

I believe it's stupid question but I don't understand how should I use [gitlab merge request push options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/#set-merge-when-pipeline-succeeds-using-git-push-options)

I have this scenario:

- I have open merge request from develop to master
- I make some changes on develop branch and push them to gitlab server with the proper option

```
git add .
git commit -m 'finish mr'
git push origin develop -o merge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds
```

- I expect that after pipelines of this commit will succeed the MR be merged but instead I get this message on gitlab MR page:

```
@user aborted the automatic merge because source branch was updated just now
@user added 1 commit just now

    8efdbde1 - finish mr
```

So it seems that the push will set MR to allow merge after succeed and immediately abort it because of commit from same push. I also tried [quick actions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html) with /merge but same result. I know there is gitlab API, but I can't use it. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

as accepted answer suggested adding target branch helped, but I also needed to add **ci.skip**:

```
git push origin $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME \
-o ci.skip \
-o merge_request.target="$MASTER_BRANCH_NAME" \
-o merge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds \
-o merge_request.create
```

Comment: I can confirm adding `-o ci.skip` to the rest of the options works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that error message updated in [`gitlab-foss` commit 882e798](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/commit/882e798caf5ac29c8f995922ce942cbe7822fc53#87e18b59e22521bee4f6fba19932f6ebd63474ed), as part of [issue 63187](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/63187) and [MR (Merge Request) 30249](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/merge_requests/30249) for recent GitLab 12.1.

That `merge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` option comes from [gitlab-foss MR 26752](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/merge_requests/26752) (GitLab 11.10, April 2019), [issue 43263](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/43263) ([release notes](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/04/22/gitlab-11-10-released/#push-and-merge-when-pipeline-succeeds)).
The MR includes:

> To create a new merge request, set its target branch, and set it to merge when its pipeline succeeds:
>
> ```
> git push -u origin -o merge_request.create \
>   -o merge_request.target=branch1 \
>   -o merge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds
> ```
>
> ### Updating existing merge requests

When pushing branches with an existing open merge request, `target` and `merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` can be used to update the merge request.

So in your case, maybe add the target:

```
git push origin develop -o merge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds \
  -o merge_request.target=master
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Sadly add target option does not help. I still get "aborted the automatic merge because source branch was updated just now". The only way I can successfully set 'merge_when_pipeline_succeeds' push option is when I also create the MR (-o merge_request.create) in same push, when no MR exists yet. So I can create MR with this option but I can't update existing one. Is it bug or is it feature? :)

Comment: @DanielBarton Probably a bug, which should means a new issue.

Comment: is it actually solved or not? Because i'm facing the same issue, 3 years later...

Comment: @KamWo I don't think this has been solved yet.